# MATLAB: Quickly write columns of strings and numerical data to a CSV file

Tags: matlab, csv, printf

I have multiple columns of data ~200,000 elements long:

```
date = {'date1','date2',...'dateN'};%Strings
column2 = [4,7,...,valueN];%Integers
column3 = [2.4,3.1,...,valueN];%Doubles
```

I need to quickly write them to a CSV file in the format

```
DateHeader,Column2Header,Column3Header
date1,4,2.4
date2,7,3.1
.,.,.
.,.,.
.,.,.
dateN,valueN,ValueN
```

I have been using:

```
fid = fopen(filename,'w+');
fprintf(fid,'%s,%s,%s\n',{'DateHeader','Column2Header','Column3Header'});
for a=1:length(date)
    fprintf(fid,'%s,',date{a});
    fprintf(fid,'%g,'column2(a));
    fprintf(fid,'%g\n'column3(a));
end
```

But this is incredably slow. It took well over a minute to write one file when it takes less than a second to read it back in using `textscan`. I am aware of `csvwrite` but this does not accept cell array inputs (It would have to be a cell array to include the date column)

Comment: Have you tried the `csvwrite` function?

Comment: ...or the dlmwrite. You can also consider writing to Excel with xlswrite and then converting to csv.

Comment: @gire Does that work with cell matrices? the documentation only mentions numeric matrices.

Comment: @Dan csvwrite only works with numeric data.

Comment: Writing to Excel, sure. If you want to write a cell check this contribution in the Matlab central: [cell2csv](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4400-cell-array-to-csv-file--cell2csv-m-)

Comment: see http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/answers/83870-fastest-way-to-write-data-to-a-text-file-fprintf

Comment: You can call `fprintf` only one time with `fprintf(fid, '%s,%g,%g\n', date{a}, column2(a), column3(a))`

Comment: You can also try with the `writetable` function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest making the changes below to see if that's enough of a performance increase for you. I've changed the file permission to `W` instead of `w+`. I think that opening the file for write only and without flushing seems to be faster. I've also changed it to a single fprintf call per loop.

```
fid = fopen(filename,'W');
fprintf(fid,'%s,%s,%s\n','DateHeader','Column2Header','Column3Header');
for a=1:length(date)
    fprintf(fid,'%s,%g,%g\n',date{a},column2(a),column3(a));
end
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `writetable` the solution becomes

```
date = {'date1','date2','dateN'};
column2 = [4,7,9];
column3 = [2.4,3.1,6.5];
headers = {'DateHeader','Column2Header','Column3Header'};

T = table(date', column2', column3', 'VariableNames', headers);
writetable(T, 'Table.csv');
```